# Updating QR or Cholesky matrix decomposition after adding a column to the original matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Let a matrix $\mathbf{X}$ with a known QR and cholesky decomposition for $\mathbf{X^TX}$. How to find the QR and cholesky decomposition for a new matrix $\mathbf{Y^TY}$ s.t. $\mathbf{Y=[X\;a]}$?

What is the reduction in computational complexity when compared to naive QR or cholesky decomposition of $\mathbf{Y}$ directly?

Comment: $Y$ is not a square matrix so it doesn't have a cholesky decomposition

Comment: @Thoth I have made the edit. Thanks for correction